# Is it acceptable to leave a capacitor across batteries even when turned off?

Tags: batteries, switches

Is it acceptable to leave a capacitor across batteries when the circuit is powered off?

The capacitor will be either an aluminum or ceramic. My concern is double sided. Making sure that the switch does not have reduced life from arcing do to the capacitor inrush every time the capacitor is switched in. Or reduced battery life do to capacitor leakage current if the capacitor is left in the circuit all the time.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fE1OAP.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: The 2nd circuit would have more of an arcing issue than the first, as the first has no real capacitance after the switch - as for leakage current it depends on your capacitor and battery, also what sort of lifetime are you looking for?

Comment: @user2813274 As long as possible but i at least 5 hours would be nice. I have not calculated the total power consumption of the total project yet. I'm trying to maximize whatever i can.

Comment: Have you looked at capacitor leakage current figures yet?  Also, just how much capacitance do you want to put in here?

Comment: Aside from your other concerns, C2 may not perform its desired function if it is too far from the load, because of the switch.

Comment: The capacitor inrush current will be very much limited by the high internal resistance of a typical 9 V block.

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel Took a look at them. I'm going to have a 220uF aluminum and 1uF ceramic. The aluminum is rated at no more than 3uA at rated voltage and the ceramic is rated at about 1.8nA.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Leaving a capacitor across the battery is fine, but read the datasheet of the capacitor you will use (or find a similar datasheet if you are using random junkbox parts). Ceramic caps will have leakage perhaps in the nA or less, whereas an electrolytic cap might be in the uA or 10's of uA range after settling for a while.

Compare this leakage current against the battery's expected self-discharge rate in its datasheet. Ballpark figure for alkaline batteries is about 80% of original capacity after one year. So let's say you are using AA batteries:

- AA battery capacity = 2500 mAh
- 80% remaining capacity after 1 year

So 20% * 2500 mAh = 500 mAh of capacity removed after 1 year

So the equivalent discharge = 500 mAh / (365 * 24 hours) = 0.057 mA = 57 uA

So maybe you want to keep the leakage current less than say 6 uA. If you're using little lithium batteries, or watch batteries, you would want way less. You can repeat the same calculations for your situation.

As the other poster mentioned, the second circuit is bad because you will have arcing whenever the switch is closed, greatly shortening the life of the switch. Even with a 1 uF cap, if it is low-ESR such as ceramic the inrush current can be 10 Amps or more if you watch it on an oscilloscope.

Answer (score 4):

The Alkaline battery is equivalent to 550mAh but has an ESR of about 10 Ohms.  In 22.5 h it can discharge 20mA when the voltage drops 1V to 8V near 0% SoC. We know the equivalent capacitance C=Ic dt/dV = 20mA 22.5h *3600sec/1V= 1620 Farads with 10 Ohm ESR approx.(if Isc =1.1A) more or less.  SO what is the point of 1uF unless there is a high frequency pulsed load such that a low ESR 1uF is much lower impedance than 10 Ohms.

If so, then the cap does nothing to degrade the storage energy in parallel across the battery and improves load regulation of very narrow pulse loads.  Otherwise it does nothing.

Putting the Cap on the load side however consumes E=1/2 CV² energy each time the cap is charged. This is only 500 μwatt-seconds so negigble  but with very low ESR surges across switch at least 1.1A depending on ESR of battery, which is enough to wet non-gold plated contacts and not serious.

The self leakage R of Alkaline batteries is often less than electrolytic capacitors, so shelf life is reduced.  With a shelf life of 5 years Rleak with 1620F is equivalent to 5y*365d *24h*3600s/1620F=Rleak=97K  so no worries if Rleak of Cap is >>1M (or 100x battery leakage)